# can't change title icon flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I try to learn flask. My test is mainly based on [this blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).
I would like to change the icon right next the title.
Here is my `base.html` :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="flask" href="../static/flask.ico" type="image/x-icon">
{% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>
{% else %}
<title>Weclome to microblog</title>
{% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <div>Microblog: <a href="/index">Home</a></div>
    <div>Ajout: <a href="add">Add</a></div>
    <div>Clean: <a href="clean">Clean</a></div>
    <hr>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The `base.html` is in the `template/` folder and the `flask.ico` is in `static/`. So all the html pages that inherite from it, should have the new icon. But it doesn't work.

I have already tried:

```
<link rel="flask" href="static/flask.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="flask" href="static/flask.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="flask" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='flask.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="flask" href="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/24/flask-icon.png" type="image/png">
```

And none of this has worked.
Thanks for your replay.

**edit**:
the solution was to change `rel="flask"` for `rel="icon"`.
Thanks

Comment: set `rel="icon"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [W3C ruling](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon), the preferred method to add a favicon to a page is to use `rel="icon"`.

Example:

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```